# response is null in android retrofit 2 with param and header

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit2, response

When I run a application and fill email / password, it show null response `(response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful())` When I log, onFailure() show nothing and onResponse() show null. How can I solve this?

MainApi,

```
public final class MainApi {

    private static String BASE_URL = "http://www.eg.com/";

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(new OkHttpClient());

    public MainApi() {
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

MainService Interface,

```
public interface MainService {

    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer fafafafafafa"})
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("auth")
    Call<Auth> postAuth(@Field("email") String email,
                        @Field("password") String password;
}
```

Activty,

```
Call<Auth> call = MainApi.createService(MainService.class).postAuth(edt_email.getText().toString(), edt_password.getText().toString());
```

Comment: you should integrate `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to detect what is happening

Comment: What's your response code?

Comment: @ArbenMaloku when `call.enqueue` , `@Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Auth> call, Response<Auth> response)`

Comment: @PPL usually you must get a response code [see here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). You can get this code using this piece of code `response.code()` When you get it please post here so maybe we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public final class MainApi {

        private static String BASE_URL = "http://www.eg.com/";
        private static MainService api;//added line
        private static Retrofit.Builder builder;

         public static MainService get(){
           if(builder== null){
            builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getClient());
                 api = builder.build().create(MainService.class);//add this line 
         }

        return api;
         }

        //Add this code
        private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        }


        public MainApi() {
        }

        public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
            Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
            return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
        }
        }
```

Comment: he is using it see this line ---> MainApi.createService(MainService.class)